# Transition not working with :target, not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: html, css

I'm just trying to create a sample of transitioning :target. The targeting works, but the transition isn't (which is just to change the background color). Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#news1 {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: background-color, 2s, ease, .1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color, 2s, ease, .1s;
    -o-transition: background-color, 2s, ease, .1s;
    -ms-transition: background-color, 2s, ease, .1s;
    transition: background-color, 2s, ease, .1s;
}
#news2 {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: background-color, 2s, ease, .1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color, 2s, ease, .1s;
    -o-transition: background-color, 2s, ease, .1s;
    -ms-transition: background-color, 2s, ease, .1s;
    transition: background-color, 2s, ease, .1s;
}
#news1:target {
    border: 2px solid #FF0000;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
}
#news2:target {
    border: 2px solid #FF0000;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p><a href="#news1">Jump to New content 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#news2">Jump to New content 2</a></p>

<p>Click on the links above and the :target selector highlight the current active HTML anchor.</p>

<p id="news1"><b>New content 1...</b></p>
<p id="news2"><b>New content 2...</b></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

remove `,` from `transition`

```
transition: background-color, 2s, ease, .1s;
```

should be

```
transition: background-color 2s ease .1s;
```

you can add `border: 2px solid transparent;` border for the targets so that they doesn't move

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/wzgnqpsq/1/

Comment: Yup. also, to make it a little less choppy when you do that, add a 2px transparent border to the original elements, if you want to transition the border too.